# Cinnamon DE not changing desktop wallpaper and not changing themes

Tags: debian, cinnamon, wallpaper

I installed Cinnamon on my Debian Linux laptop, But now it won't let me change the wallpaper or the theme, when I click on the wallpaper I want it just highlights it but leaves it as the default Debian wallpaper, and when I click the theme I want it doesn't change the Icons at all